# What is the best way to reseal a balcony flooring that has started to peel?

Tags: flooring, balcony, weatherproof

I have a balcony over living space on the 2nd floor of my home. Although the balcony is covered, the area near the opening is exposed to rain resulting in some peeling away of the coating and the substrate below is exposed.  I believe that the substrate is some type of concrete, based on it's texture.  I would like to reseal the entire flooring with new paint and was considering applying Zinzer 123 primer and a final coat of Sherwin Williams exterior acrylic latex. Would sanding the areas where the original coating had peeled provide a uniform appearance?  Any suggestions on how to maintain a textured floor appearance?
[image: balcony overview]

[image: peeling coating close-up]

[image: balcony flooring]

Answer (score 2):

Scrape the loose flaking areas  until you get to areas that still have good adhesion.

Once all the loose stuff is off, coat with [*XIM Peel Bond*](https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/xim/primers-sealers/peel-bond) which will lock the surrounding areas down, it acts like a glue for flaky paint. I have used this product extensively.

After that cures, wash the deck and clean of all dirt and debris and prime as directed by the product of your choice (*if priming is required*).

I would encourage you to find an elastomeric coating designed for walking surfaces and follow the manufacturer directions for application, *Gaco Deck*, is a quality product and can be applied over previously coated decks.

As far as building up the damaged areas for a uniform topcoat, you might need to use an exterior wood filler and spot prime that area before apply your deck coating.

Comment: Matt, wouldn’t it be preferable to build up the damaged areas with a concrete filler rather than a wood filler? Are there any recommendations for a concrete filler?

Comment: @Grant Good catch. I personally don't have much experience with concrete fillers, I would assume a patching compound would be sufficient.